# AWS Glue not accepting additional python library

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I am running my python job using below command

```
runId = glue.start_job_run(JobName=glueJobName, Arguments={'--extra-py-files': 's3://<bucket>/<path>/paramFile.py'})
```

The paramFile.py has variable in below format

`x = 5`

`y = 10`

In glue console, I am trying to access those variables

```
print("x:", x)

print("y:", y)
```

But the glue job is failing with below error.
NameError: Name 'x' is not defined

I tried with both paramFile.py and paramFile.zip. Both didn't worked out. Also, I placed the file under S3 path where glue script located and that didn't worked out too.

AWS documentation indicate that "If your library only consists of a single Python module in one .py file, you do not need to place it in a .zip file.". Hence, I believe we don't need to zip the file.

I have not placed an *init* file. Not sure, if that is causing the issue.

Comment: `X = 5` That is a capital X.  Your print statement is using a lowercase x.

Comment: sorry, it was small letter x only. It was a typo from my end.

Comment: try `from paramfile import x, y`

Comment: That is not working too...it is failing with below error.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paramFile.py'; 'paramFile' is not a package.`